# JQuery .click() on specific nested div change css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried all the solutions from similar questions, but nothing seems to work. Please help me out. The goal is to change the color of the clicked div, and only of that div. My code changes the color of every div.

Here is the [JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ukukgx8v/3/). It would be cool if there is an explanation why this happens.

**JQuery**

```
// This is the clicking part.
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).children('div').css("background", "blue");
});

// The part below creates the boxes.
$("#createBtn").click(function() {
  createBoxes();
  createGrid();
});

$('#test').click(function() {
  alert($("#numBox").val());
  //$(this).hide();
});

var boxes = [];

function createBoxes() {
  boxes = [];
  var numBox = $("#numBox").val();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numBox; i++) {
    boxes.push(i);
    boxes.push(i);
  }
}

function createGrid() {
  $("#grid").html("");
  var x = shuffleArray(boxes);
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var box = "<div id='box" + i + "' class='box'>" + x[i] + "</div>";
    $("#grid").append(box);
  }
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

**HTML**

```
Boxes: 
<select id="numBox">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
<button id="createBtn">Create</button>
<button id="test">Test</button>

<div id="grid">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid {
  height:300px; 
  width:236px;
  background:green; 
  padding:10px;
}

.box {
  height:50px; 
  width:50px; 
  background:red;
  float:left; 
  margin:2px;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) bind the `click` event.

```
$(document).on('click','.box',function() {
    $(this).css("background", "blue");
});
```

**working demo** https://jsfiddle.net/ukukgx8v/17/

Comment: You may want to change that to `$(document).on('click', '.box', ...)`. Otherwise the handler will be called multiple times, once for every parent div of the box.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. Is this the only/recommended way to do this? @Flocke provided another working example.

Comment: @Ivan ‘s answer bind the `click` event for every `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing all children of your div.
Just change the event.target:

```
$('div').click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).css("background", "blue");
```

});

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukukgx8v/15/

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
// This is the clicking part.
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).children('div').css("background", "blue");
});
```

And add this as first command to "createGrid":

```
$('.box').unbind('click');
```

And add this as last command to the same function "createGrid":

```
// This is the clicking part.
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "blue");
});
```

The working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ukukgx8v/13/

Answer (score 0):

you can change createGrid function by adding

```
  $('#grid div.box').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "blue");
});
```

try this

```js
$("#createBtn").click(function() {
  createBoxes();
  createGrid();
});

$('#test').click(function() {
  alert($("#numBox").val());
  //$(this).hide();
});

var boxes = [];

function createBoxes() {
  boxes = [];
  var numBox = $("#numBox").val();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numBox; i++) {
    boxes.push(i);
    boxes.push(i);
  }
}

function createGrid() {
  $("#grid").html("");
  var x = shuffleArray(boxes);
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var box = "<div id='box" + i + "' class='box'>" + x[i] + "</div>";
    $("#grid").append(box);
  }
  $('#grid div.box').click(function() {
 $(this).css("background", "blue");
});
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

```css
#grid {
  height:300px; 
  width:236px;
  background:green; 
  padding:10px;
}
 
.box {
  height:50px; 
  width:50px; 
  background:red;
  float:left; 
  margin:2px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Boxes: 
<select id="numBox">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
<button id="createBtn">Create</button>
<button id="test">Test</button>

<div id="grid">
</div>
```